# Why I can't create a linked list with a circle?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to create a linkedlist with a infinite circle like this `0->1->2->3->4->5-**>2**->3->4->5-**>2**->3->4->5-> .........`, below is my code:

```
class node():

    def __init__(self, val):
           self.val = val
           self.nextNode = None
    
    def __repr__(self):
           return "%s" % self.val
    
class linkedList():

    def __init__(self):
           self.head = None

    def addNode(self, nodeVal):
           newNode = node(nodeVal)
           if self.head is None:
               self.head = newNode
           else:
               tmp = self.head
               while tmp.nextNode is not None:
                   tmp = tmp.nextNode
               tmp.nextNode = newNode
    
    def linkNode(self, node):
           if self.head is None:
               raise Exception("list can't be None")
           tmp = self.head
           while tmp.nextNode is not None:
               tmp = tmp.nextNode
           tmp.nextNode = node
            
    def __repr__(self):           
           tmp = self.head
           val = []
           while tmp is not None:
               val.append(tmp.val)
               tmp = tmp.nextNode
           return "vals are %s" % val

           
s = linkedList()

head = node(0)
node1 = node(1)
node2 = node(2)
node3 = node(3)
node4 = node(4)
node5 = node(5)

s.addNode(head)
s.addNode(node1)
s.addNode(node2)
s.addNode(node3)
s.addNode(node4)
s.addNode(node5)
s.linkNode(node2)

print(s)
```

But the output is this: vals are `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2]` which is not a circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your method `addNode` expects a value, and will create a node for it, you should not call it with a node as argument.

So without altering your class methods, your main code could be as below. BTW, I find `s` a bad name for a list -- it is often used for a string -- so I named it `lst` instead:

```
lst = linkedList()

lst.addNode(0)
lst.addNode(1)
lst.addNode(2)
lst.addNode(3)
lst.addNode(4)
lst.addNode(5)

lst.linkNode(lst.next.next)

print(lst)
```

Not related, but here are some ways to improve your class:

- as `addNode` each time needs to traverse the whole list, it might be good for your linked list to maintain a reference to the tail node. That way you can append a new node at the end in constant time.
- `addNode` could also *return* the newly added node, so you can use that later for your call to `linkNode`

Here is how your code would look after implementing those ideas:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def addNode(self, nodeVal):
        newNode = node(nodeVal)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = newNode
        else:
            self.tail.next = newNode
        self.tail = newNode
        return newNode
    
    def linkNode(self, node):
        if self.head is None:
            raise Exception("list can't be None")
        self.tail.next = node

# Main code
lst = linkedList()

lst.addNode(0)
lst.addNode(1)
backref = lst.addNode(2)
lst.addNode(3)
lst.addNode(4)
lst.addNode(5)

lst.linkNode(backref)

print(lst)
```

Comment: Great, the solution plus the refactors is yummy!

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because in `addNode` you are creating a new node by doing

```
newNode = node(nodeVal)
```

which means when you later pass node2 to `linkNode` it is still a node with `nextNode=None` as create by the `class Node`

Just remove that line and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

A small detail is needed, then it should work as you intend.

- Replace your line `s.linkNode(node2)` with `s.linknode(s.head.nextNode.nextNode)`

Then to print the x first elements in the cycle use the following:

```
tmp = s.head
for i in range(x):
    print(tmp.val)
    tmp = tmp.nextNode
```

- Note don't do `print(s)`, as that will do an infinite loop in the cycle

The reason for the previous not working, is that you have in the function `addNode()` the following `newNode = node(nodeVal)` so it creates new nodes with no connection to the list.